# NSString Range how it works?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsrange

I'm just playing around with Xcode, and now using Xcode to find some string in another string. And problem here is that it doesn't show what I expect. (It shows "No match found!")
Any tips, please?
Thanks,

And my code is :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {



        NSString *listOfNames = @"huhuWARDdsfadfadsfsadfafsfsadfafr";
        NSString *capListOfNames = [listOfNames capitalizedString];

        NSString *name = @"WaRd";
        NSString *capName = [name capitalizedString];



        NSRange match = [capListOfNames rangeOfString:capName];
        if (match.location == NSNotFound)
        {
            NSLog(@"No match faound!");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Found!");
            NSLog(@"location : %d",(int)match.location);
            NSLog(@"length : %d",(int)match.length);


        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`capitalizedString` returns your string with an uppercase first letter and the rest lowercase.

Try again with `capName = [name uppercaseString];`

Currently, you're looking for `"Ward"` in a string that doesn't contain `"Ward"` (though it does contain `"WARD"`).

EDIT: `capitalizedString` makes the first letter in each word of the string upper case, and the rest lower case.

---

Also, you can do this:

```
NSRange match = [capListOfNames rangeOfString:capName 
                                      options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Which, well, performs a case-insensitive search...

Answer (score 1):

`capitalizedString` only makes the first letter capitalized, use `uppercaseString` instead to achive what you expect.